# Variable "name" does not exist in UsersListBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 1 - Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am getting this error using Symfony 2 while fetching all users from database:

```
 Variable "name" does not exist in UsersListBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 1
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
```

My code: `index.html.twig`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Symfony 2 Example</title>
<link href="/bundles/userslist/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1>User list page</h1>
    <div id="body">
        <p><a href="/">Click here</a> to back to the Homepage</p>
        <p><a href="users/add">ADD NEW USER</a></p>
        <p>All users in the users table using: <br />
        <strong>$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UsersListBundle:Users');<br />
        $users = $repository->findAll();</strong></p>
        {% if users is not empty %)
            <table cellpadding="4">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Phone</strong></td>
                </tr>
                {% for user in users %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
                        <td><a href="users/edit/{{ user.id }}">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="users/delete/{{ user.id }}">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        {% else %}
            <p>No users in the database</p>
        {% endif %}
        <p>Get ID 1 in the example table using: <br />
        <strong>$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UsersListBundle:Users')->find(1);</strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
/**
     * @Route("/users")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('UsersListBundle:Users');

        $users = $repository->findAll();

        return array('users' => $users);
    }
```

I have read some articles about this error. They say something about a hidden character. This character occurs when you hit Alt Gr + Space.
Now I dont know how to remove that character. I tried retyping same code but no luck.

Here is my User Entity:

```
<?php
// src/Users/Bundle/ListBundle/Entity/Users.php

namespace Users\Bundle\ListBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }
}
```

Here is my UserController:

```
<?php

namespace Users\Bundle\ListBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Users\Bundle\ListBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/users")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('UsersListBundle:Users');

        $users = $repository->findAll();

        return array('users' => $users);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/users/add")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {

        $user= new Users();
        $user->setName('Name');
        $user->setEmail('Email');
        $user->setPhone('Phone');

        $form=$this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('name')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('phone')
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->getMethod()=='POST'){
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()){
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_list_users_index'), 301);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('UsersListBundle:Users:add.html.twig',array(
                'form'=>$form->createView(),
            ));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/users/edit/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        if ($id == 0){ // no user id entered
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_list_users_index'), 301);
        }
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('UsersListBundle:Users')
            ->find($id);

        if (!$user) {// no user in the system
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No user found for id '.$id
            );
        }

        $form=$this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('name')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('phone')
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->getMethod()=='POST'){
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()){
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_list_users_index'), 301);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('UsersListBundle:Users:edit.html.twig',array(
                'form'=>$form->createView(),
            ));
        }

        return array('name' => $id);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/users/delete/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function deleteAction($id)
    {
        if ($id == 0){ // no user id entered
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_list_users_index'), 301);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('UsersListBundle:Users')->find($id);

        if (!$user) { // no user in the system
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No user found for id '.$id
            );
        } else {
            $em->remove($user);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_list_users_index'), 301);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Show us `Users` entity. 2. What happens if you don't use `name` in twig?

Comment: As I asked; What happens when you get rid of `{{ user.name }}` part? Does it trigger different errors or what?

Comment: That specific error got fix. I guess it was a cache issue. Not the code. But now the issue is that my default view is calling. I want to call: views/Users/index.html.twig instead of views/Default/index.html.twig. I have updated my question and added my UsersController code.

Answer (score 1):

You have an syntax issue on this line :

```
{% if users is not empty %)
```

Replace **%)** by **%}**

Comment: Shouldn't symfony show me that there is a syntax error? I guess it should

Comment: I just copy/pasted your html and then Symfony2 throw me this exception : "Unexpected ")" in index.html.twig at line 17". I don't know what IDE your using but some IDE show you if there is something wrong (like PHPStorm).

Comment: I am using Adobe dreamweaver cs6. But why does it matter?

Comment: IDE choice is not the main subject of this topic but you can avoid syntax errors with some IDE which alert you if there is an error.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: The error still exists. even after fixing the syntax error.

Comment: I emptied the whole index.html.twig file but error still exists

Comment: The same error?

Can you try in the twig  `{% dump(users) %}` and give us the result ? please

Comment: Can you try to : clear the cache, check the file encoding (UTF-8 without BOM), comment the line `<td>{{ user.name }}</td>` ? please

Comment: That specific error got fix. I guess it was a cache issue. Not the code. But now the issue is that my default view is calling. I want to call: views/Users/index.html.twig instead of views/Default/index.html.twig. I have updated my question and added my UsersController code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do not have such field name.
Are this error on line 1 at:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
```

or at:

```
   <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
```

try to delete second and check if still have error.

could you show me in twig dump of users or UsersListBundle:Users entity

```
  .....
  {% if users is not empty %)
  {% dump(users) %}
  .....
```

Comment: In users table I have id name email phone fields. And the table is empty. Technically it shouldn't access the for loop

Comment: It tells me that the error is on line 1. Which is <Document> tag

Comment: I emptied the whole index.html.twig file but the error still exists

Comment: if error still exist then index.html.twig isn't called,  you are sure that this twig template are called?  check for other index.html.twig template. maybe under "Default" folder "UsersListBundle:Default:index.html.twig"

Comment: This is another index.html.twig file under, views/Default/index.html.twig

Comment: for second answer
replace: 
   return array('users' => $users);
with:  
    return $this->render('UsersListBundle:Users:index.html.twig',array(
                'users'=>$users, 
            ));

Comment: I replaced the line but its still the same as before. Its opening the index.html.twig from views/Default/

Comment: maybe clear cache again? how you coud change code, but result are same.
UsersListBundle:Users:index.html.twig
translates as bundle:directory:file
under Resources/views/directory/file
default directory are called only then you type bundle:file

Answer (score 0):

If you added or renamed the 'name' field in the database, you have to regenerate your entity. Adding the Users entity to your question would help you get a faster response.

Comment: Please check out my question. I just updated and provided a user entity